# Is there a word for someone who tied a game akin to "winner" and "loser"?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

Someone who wins a game is a winner.
Someone who loses a game is a loser.

Is there a word for someone who tied / ended a game in a draw?

Comment: Leveler, maybe?

Comment: Do you want this word to be a good thing or a bad thing?

Comment: Equalizer..........

Comment: @Jim good question. Is there a good word and a bad word?

Comment: ***Drawer***, obviously.

Comment: @Clare I can't find any dictionary definition that would fit that meaning.

Comment: @DanBron -- I'm glad you were able to get that off your chest.